# Separar resultados de uma query SQL por data

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

EStou criando uma query em SQL que será usada em um sistema/relatório e me deparei com o seguinte problema. Ela tem dois resultados, um que exibe o tempo total entre os dias pesquisados e outra que será exibido dia por dia. 
A Dificuldade  no caso está na segunda tela que tenho que criar.

A Consulta no Caso é assim

```
SELECT ocorrencias.[GITEC]
,SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, ocorrencias.[INICIO], ocorrencias.[FECHAMENTO 
OCORRÊNCIA])) as Total_Indispo 

FROM [REPORT].[dbo].[report_sirea] ocorrencias INNER JOIN [REPORT]. 
  [dbo].[planta_circuitos] circuitos
  ON ocorrencias.[CIRCUITO] = circuitos.[DESIGNACAO] WHERE
   ocorrencias.[INICIO] BETWEEN '2019-07-01' AND '2019-07-03 23:59:59'

   AND ocorrencias.[FECHAMENTO OCORRÊNCIA] IS NOT NULL
    AND ocorrencias.[GITEC] = 'GITEC/BH' 
    AND circuitos.[TIPO_PONTO] NOT IN ('LOTERICOS', 
   'BACKBONE','INTERLIGAÇÃO - BACKBONE') 
   GROUP BY ocorrencias.[GITEC]
   ORDER BY [ocorrencias].[GITEC]
```

No caso também teria que apresentar os resultados de forma dinâmica em separado, No caso precisaria mostrar no dia 01, depois o dia 02 e por ultimo o dia 03.

É possível fazer isso direto no SQL só usando um Select ou precisaria de algo a mais(Function, Procedure) ou precisaria fazer isso direto na linguagem PHP?

No caso, estou usando o SQL Server de Banco de Dados.

Comment: você pode fazer uma procedure que vai carregando todos os resultados numa tabela temporária e retorna tudo de uma vez ao final com todos os resultados que precisa. Uma outra solução seria montar vários selects, executar todos e pagar os vários resultados usando `mysqli_multi_query`. Se precisar de ajuda com alguma dessas opções posso ajudar com uma resposta

Comment: Você consegue informar a estrutura das tabelas, dados de exemplo para as mesmas e um resultado esperado relativo à esses dados de exemplo? Sem isso é difícil visualizar o que você quer

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar uma `CTE` com os dias entre as datas da seguinte forma:

```
WITH dias AS (
  SELECT CAST('2019-07-01' AS DATE) AS dia,
         1 AS sequencia
   UNION ALL
  SELECT CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 1, dia) AS DATE),
         sequencia + 1
    FROM dias
   WHERE dia < '2019-07-03 23:59:59'
)
SELECT d.dia
  FROM dias d
 ORDER BY d.sequencia
```

Depois apenas aplique na sua `query`:

```
WITH dias AS (
  SELECT CAST('2019-07-01' AS DATE) AS dia,
         1 AS sequencia
   UNION ALL
  SELECT CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 1, dia) AS DATE),
         sequencia + 1
    FROM dias
   WHERE dia < '2019-07-03 23:59:59'
)
SELECT d.dia,
       ocorrencias.[GITEC],
       SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, ocorrencias.[INICIO], ocorrencias.[FECHAMENTO OCORRÊNCIA])) as Total_Indispo
  FROM [REPORT].[dbo].[report_sirea] ocorrencias
 INNER JOIN [REPORT]. [dbo].[planta_circuitos] circuitos
    ON ocorrencias.[CIRCUITO] = circuitos.[DESIGNACAO]
 INNER JOIN dias d
    ON CAST(ocorrencias.[INICIO] AS DATE) = dia
 WHERE ocorrencias.[FECHAMENTO OCORRÊNCIA] IS NOT NULL
   AND ocorrencias.[GITEC] = 'GITEC/BH'
   AND circuitos.[TIPO_PONTO] NOT IN ('LOTERICOS', 'BACKBONE','INTERLIGAÇÃO - BACKBONE')
 GROUP BY ocorrencias.[GITEC]
 ORDER BY d.dia, [ocorrencias].[GITEC];
```